# Let´s encrypt and cloudfare

Tags: cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I just moved my sites behind Cloudflare CDN and realized that instead of Lets Encrypt certificates I have  their Comodo certificate

I´m generally fine with that but I would like to understand.

Do I need to renew and bother with my LE certificates while I´m behind Cloudflare? 
Thank you

[image: certificate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yet

Long answer is there're two things:

1. Traffic from users to CF: CF cert is served
2. Traffic from CF to your web server: it depends on how you setup your site with CF. If you let CF access your site by port 443,  then yes you need to maintain your own cert on your server. If you let CF access your web using port 80 only, then you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you cannot use LE certs while behind CloudFlare. This is because the LE system will not be able to resolve the IP address of your server while doing a dns lookup. You'll have to use the CF supplied origin certificate instead.